# Can creatures outside a Leomund's Tiny Hut use ammunition that was fired from inside the hut to attack creatures inside the hut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ammunition

I've not seen comments on this interpretation, so what can anyone tell me about enemies picking up arrows shot out of the hut and shooting them back in (albeit at obscured creatures inside)?  Do those arrows get a pass since they were inside the hut when cast?

Comment: We can't answer why the designer did something (that's designer intent), but we can answer whether your question at the end about using ammunition that left. I've adjusted your question, but you can always roll back or edit it!

Comment: And welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate :)

Comment: Get a pass? I must be missing context as to why they wouldn't be able to use the ammunition. Is it magic ammunition or something? If it is a spell, it should be stated clearly.

Comment: I checked the edits to see that it was a spell and made an edit to show it.

Comment: It might be useful to know that RAI you can't shoot arrows through a tiny hunt spell whether they are on creatures inside it or not. https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/06/22/moving-through-leomunds-tiny-hut/

Answer (score 19):

The relevant part of the [*Leomund's Tiny Hut*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut) (PHB, 255) spell description states:

> Creatures and objects⁠ within the dome when you cast this spell can
>   move through it freely. All other creatures and objects⁠ are barred
>   from passing through it.

Based on that description, in order to pass out of the dome, the arrows would have had to be inside the dome initially.  If they were inside the dome initially, it should be possible to shoot them back inside the dome as well.

Comment: It may be helpful to add a caveat about the potential non-recover-ability of ammunition (eg, as discussed here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92203/is-ammunition-recoverable-and-reusable ).

Comment: @minnmass To be more direct, the rules say that it takes **a minute** to search a battlefield for ammo, and you recover **half** of the ammo used.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention that RAI you can't shoot arrows out of a tiny hut wether they were on a creature inside it or not https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/06/22/moving-through-leomunds-tiny-hut/